# How to make a copy(Deep Copy) of an Object of type List<List<Integer>> by value?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I tried many ways to copy an object without referencing it, and it's seems to me all of them shallow copy not deep.

Let's say I have sent an Object of type `java List<List<Integer>>` using parameters from main to a method.

```java
void reverseMatrix(List<List<Integer> > grid)
{

}
```

so I defined List> tempGrid= new ArrayList<>(); inside this method above, and I want to copy all the values(by value not by reference.)

I tried Iterator as below :

```java
Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = grid.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            tempGrid.add(iterator.next());
        }
```

after applying the code above it, still, change the parent object(grid) not tempGrid.

If I applied this code `java tempGrid.get(0).set(0,1);`
it will change grid too.

I saw some subject about iterate by values.

```java
        List<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<>();

   for(List<Integer> list: grid){
          for(Integer numb: list) {
              temp1.add(numb);
          }
          tempGrid.add(temp1);
      }
```

I tried to use Collections.copy, but give me error, that des size not fit to source.

I expect to get a new object not get effected by operations on the old object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) objects are immutable so you don't need to deep copy them.

Both the outer and inner lists are mutable, so they need to be copied. Assuming we don't need to retain the list *type*, e.g. [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) vs [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), we can simply use the [`ArrayList(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) constructor to copy the inner lists.

Using code that doesn't require Java 8:

```java
static void deepCopy(List<List<Integer>> input) {
    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
    for (List<Integer> inner : input)
        output.add(new ArrayList<>(inner));
    return output;
}
```